# Why is Scanner.nextDouble throwing a InputMismatchException for numbers separated by "," or ";"?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

I am trying to read coordinates from a file.  The format is start point, end point, polygons.  Here is an example:

```
1, 3
34, 19
0, 14; 6, 19; 9, 15; 7, 8; 1, 9
2, 6; 17, 6; 17, 1; 2, 1
```

I read each line using a BufferedReader and have confirmed that is working.  I am trying to use `Scanner` to parse each line for the numbers as doubles, so I use Scanner's `nextDouble` method, but when I run the code it throws a `InputMismatchException` on the first read.  Here is the logic of those lines:

File line - "1, 3"

Code:
`lineReader.nextDouble();`

Any ideas?

Comment: where is your code. give us some important details.

Comment: The code is a few hundreds of lines long and wouldn't be very useful here, but I'll add a bit to the question.

Comment: These hundreds of lines are almost always can be compressed into [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which may or may not be related to the original code.

Comment: I believe that `Scanner` assumes that its input is separated with whitespaces, so you have to either alter its behavior (if possible) or read these commans/semicolons manually. Say, if you call `nextDouble()`, it reads `1`, then you call it one more time, it will probably fail because it can only read `,`.

Comment: Another probable reason is `,` being decimal separator in your locale, so `Scanner` is confused by `,` followed with space.

Comment: I thought this might be the case, so I tried to use a delimiter on commas and semi-colons like so" `lineReader.useDelimiter([,;]);` but that didn't work.  I'm not sure if that's how you do it though.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer to [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class. Its having example of, how to use delimiters with `Scanner`.

> **Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\s*fish\\s*");**

Below is the example which is reading your input from a file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("D:/INPUT_OUTPUT/Data_Stack.txt"))) {

        // Adding delimiters.
        in.useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*|\\s*\\n\\s*|\\s*;\\s*");

        // Reading files.
        while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
            System.out.println(in.nextDouble());
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Data in the file (**Data_Stack.txt**)-:

```
1, 3
34, 19
0, 14; 6, 19; 9, 15; 7, 8; 1, 9
2, 6; 17, 6; 17, 1; 2, 1
```

**Output-:**

```
1.0
3.0
34.0
19.0
0.0
14.0
6.0
19.0
9.0
15.0
7.0
8.0
1.0
9.0
2.0
6.0
17.0
6.0
17.0
1.0
2.0
1.0
```

**Description-:** From [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) we can see that-:

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern,
>   which by default matches whitespace.

So we have to add required delimiter to read our data. Required delimiters are `,`, `\n` and `;` which have been added in line  `in.useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*|\\s*\\n\\s*|\\s*;\\s*");` of code.
After adding delimiters to `Scanner` its reading data correctly.

Comment: I have read through the delimiter example, but it doesn't really explain it too well.  Is the extra `\\`` in `\\s*` a break character?  I'm assuming `|` means OR.  Why do we need any number of white spaces between `,`, `;`, and `\n`?  Also, how the heck do you just write the break character in code quotes haha

Answer (score -1):

Scanner.next() is '1,',the type is String.

Try below code:

```
    while(scanner.hasNext()){
        if (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
            System.out.println("double="+scanner.nextDouble());
        }else{
            System.out.println("string="+scanner.next());
        }
    }
```

Then you can understand.